# 'he prepared the design' or 'he designed'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here are my constructions:

> 1. While carrying out his engineering project, **he prepared the design
>      of** wired and wireless network infrastructure and developed the new
>      architectural plans of the building.
> 2. While carrying out his engineering project, **he designed** wired and
>      wireless network infrastructure and developed the new architectural
>      plans of the building.

So my question is, should I use 'he prepared the design' or 'he designed'?

Comment: The second is better. Does this phrase add anything? While carrying out his engineering project...?   I'd describe the building.  "...of a 100-storey high-rise office complex" or whatever terms accurately portray the scope of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Thr use of active verbs is almost always preferable. "Prepared" doesn't describe or convey the kind of action implied by "designed." As a result, I would work to avoid the "prepared the design" construct in favor of the simpler, more concise "he designed."